# All physical memory is mapped into virtual address of kernel?

Tags: kernel

I am studying device driver recently, and get reminded of the concepts of virtual memory. Although I attended Computer Architecture classes when I was student, however, honestly speaking, virtual memory is so complicated from concepts that it always confused me. I am a EE guy, so, please explain from the view of **BIG PICTURE** that really distinguish this concept. I can dig into technique details myself.

When we are talking about virtual memory, we are talking about the memory allocation method for a process. Process is the one that virtual memory serves, right? For a 32-bit system with 4GB address space, 0-3G is usually assigned to user space virtual address, and 3-4G space is assigned to kernel. This is what called 3G/1G division, from the post listed below:

http://users.nccs.gov/~fwang2/linux/lk_addressing.txt

However, this post also illustrated that **ALL PHYSICAL MEMORY IS MAPPED INTO KERNEL SPACE**, and nothing for user space. This really confused me. I list this part in the post here:

#

Thus, in the 3G/1G split, kernel has the virtual address space of 1GB.
Remember that to access a physical address, you need a virtual address to
start with, even for kernel. So if you don't do anything special, the 1GB
virtual address effectively limits the physical space a kernel can access to
1GB. Okay, maybe this is a third less obvious detail: kernel *needs* to access
*every* physical memory to make full use of it.

In the early days, where a machine's physical space is much less than 1GB, it
is OK, the whole physical memory is mapped to this 1GB virtual address.

```
   process address space 

4GB +---------------+
    |     512MB     |
    +---------------+ <------+     physical memory               
    |     512MB     |        | 
3GB +---------------+ <--+   +---> +------------+ 
    |               |    |         |   512 MB   |
    |     /////     |    +-------> +------------+
    |               |     
0GB +---------------+
```

#

And this post also illustrate the same thing when physical memory is above 2G:

#

```
                                       physical mem
   process address space    +------> +------------+
                            |        |  3200 M    |
                            |        |            |
4GB +---------------+ <-----+        |  HIGH MEM  |
    |     128 MB    |                |            |
    +---------------+ <---------+    |            |
    +---------------+ <------+  |    |            | 
    |     896 MB    |        |  +--> +------------+         
3GB +---------------+ <--+   +-----> +------------+ 
    |               |    |           |   896 MB   |
    |     /////     |    +---------> +------------+
    |               |     
0GB +---------------+
```

#

My questions is, why all  physical memory mapped into kernel space? None to the lower 0-3G user space?

I think I missed something related to the big picture behind that post, but, what I have missed?

Thanks for your time and efforts!

Answer (score 3):

A page that has a mapping **`DOES NOT`** automatically mean it is lying somewhere in the physical memory. It merely gives you the address of `where to look for the page` in physical memory.

In any case, typically we have a memory heirarchy. A three level hierarchy is not atypical these days. So it is very much likely that a given memory address could be found in one of these caches. If it isn't then the kernel will have to start it's page replacement algorithm by evicting (unlocked) pages from the memory.

The only difference between user and kernel pages, AFAIK, is that kernel pages have a "higher" privileged code allowing it to access privileged instructions and in case of 32bit Linux the Kernel portion of any given process will always have a **fixed virtual address space** that does **NOT** change between process context switches. And to simplify and therefore fasten the translation to physial address, the mapping is also fixed by a pre-configured offset. Other than that there isn't much difference between a user space page and a kernel space page. Both of them "compete" for the physical memory.

In any case, it is the scheduler which determines which entity to run next, whether it is a regular user space process, a kernel control path (piggybacking on the current process) or a kernel thread. Depending on that decision, the swapper will swap out pages from the RAM to make room and then will swap in pages from the chosen entity.

An interrupt has an altogether different context bypassing the scheduler completely leaving the CPU at it's mercy. In that case the ISR will be run which will also access virtual memory. If the pages corresponding to the ISR are not resident in memory, a double fault will occur and it usually shows poor programming by the author. How these are handled vary from architecture to architecture. Some process the fault until a certain point, some throw a kernel OOPs message and halt. Nevertheless, what is relevant to your question here is that even the ISRs which have the highest priority in the system (way above processes/threads) have to make sure there is enough memory to do the job.

P.S: In this discussion we are assuming all our cache requests are a miss so we have to go all the way to the RAM (which is again packed full).

Answer (score 1):

The user space part of virtual memory has mappings to physical memory as well. The linked article is about how the kernel is able to access all physical memory. So for brevity, user space mappings are simply left out of the diagrams.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have figured out my question several hours after I posted this. That post is talking about when process get into kernel space. Under this case, kernel needs to access the whole physical memory, and that post is explaining how.