# kernel memory vs user memory allocations

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

So I am currently trying to understand how page frame allocation works when it comes to kernel memory vs user space memory.

As I understand it, normal kernel memory is contiguously mapped to physical memory. Essentially, there is just an offset from Virtual -> Physical.

User space does not have that constraint, and large blocks of virtual allocations can be spread all over the physical memory.

Using the usual 1g/3g split for a 32bit system as an example:

```
Physical RAM 
----------------
3g     <- Mapped in user space
----------------
1g     <- Contiguously mapped in kernel space 
----------------
```

So my question:

Lets say the kernel is currently using 128MB of physical memory, so there is loads of its 986mb (physical) available.

Now a user process would like some memory. Theoretically the kernel could find a free page frame in the lower 1gb of physical memory and give that to a user process. This of course would reduce the amount of memory available to the kernel (before triggering paging), as you are taking page frames within its 1GB contiguous area.

So it seems that a sensible way to allocate page frames would be something like:

page frames for kernel memory: Low to High
page frames for user memory: High to Low

That way page frames not used by the kernel can be used by user processes, but only after all of the memory outside of the kernel's memory map has been used.

On a very basic level, is this how the Linux kernel allocates page frames?

Comment: What is your programming problem?

Comment: @marekful I am not asking about a programming problem. I am asking about an algorithm that I do not understand. (Page frame allocation in the Linux kernel)

Comment: Wrong forum, sorry. Try kernel.org.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic " but if your question generally covers… a software algorithm, or.." 

Seems good to me?

Also, related questions have been asked on here already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29178416/1103741